# Why isn't my AngularJS $scope.$watch being triggered on service changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller, I have:
var timespanServiceFn;

```
timespanServiceFn = function() {
  return timespanService.getTimespan();
};

$scope.$watch(timespanServiceFn, $scope.updateVolume());
```

My `$scope.updateVolume()` function just has a `console.log` so that I know I got there.

My `timespanService` is also super simple:

```
myApp.service('timespanService', [
  '$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var currentTimespan;
    currentTimespan = '3M';
    this.getTimespan = function() {
      return currentTimespan;
    };
    this.setTimespan = function(timespan) {
      console.log('setting timespan to', timespan);
      return currentTimespan = timespan;
    };
  }
]);
```

So why is it that when I changed the timespan, the `$watch` doesn't get triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch takes two functions as arguments. You must pass the second parameter as argument but you just called it there:

```
$scope.$watch(timespanServiceFn, $scope.updateVolume());
```

so the return statement of `$scope.updateVolume()` will be passed to `$watch` function instead of the function definition itself.

Just change it to:

```
$scope.$watch(timespanServiceFn, $scope.updateVolume);
```

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3v9Nv/2/)**